# Mutliplatform application: (Automated) Testing for Mac OSX howto?

Tags: macos, testing, cloud, multiplatform

I have a firefox based application(ff extension) that is supposedly/allegedly working on Mac OSX too. I wish to make the application formally supported in Mac OSX. For that, I need to incorporate automated tests in the build process specific to Mac OSX.

With ubiquitous availability of Windows and Linux as cloud offering, executing automated tests for these platforms is easy. Not so with Mac OSX.

Any suggestions on how to go about the (light) automated testing for Mac OSX? 
[PS:I have come across MediaTemple's OSX cloud in private beta. No luck for me in getting an invite.]

Comment: I am moving this to Stackoverflow. It is more programming related then a SuperUser question

Comment: I've got this same issue, to test PHP code which uses OS-specific cli commands.

Comment: How are you testing your application currently? And how is is platform specific?

Comment: It's PHP...PHP running platform-specific code (such as finding the CPU vendor).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of testing you'd like to perform, but why don't you install OS X on VMWare and test within the virtual machine? See this SO question if that is an option for you:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159/is-it-possible-to-run-osx-in-a-virtual-machine

Comment: I'd like to do so on VirtualBox, but I can't seem to find a (legal) copy of OSX anywhere (to buy it, of course).

Comment: I am not a lawyer, so cannot comment on the licensing terms, but there are a lot of them on amazon.com, ebay.com, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a combination of Selenium(www.seleniumhq.org) and Sikuli (http://sikuli.org/) would work for you?

Selenium to drive anything web based in FireFox and Sikuli to do all the rest. The tools work all fine together with Java API support. Both tools platform independent.

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what test you are trying to automate, but if it is command line based (as the comments seem to suggest it is php code under test), then you can install a VM with darwin on it and perform your tests there. Mac OS X being based on darwin should give you similar results. However as I don't know what the test entails there is no guarantee.

You can find the darwin release for Snow Leopard [here](http://svn.macosforge.org/repository/darwinbuild/trunk), 10.5 is [here](http://svn.macosforge.org/repository/darwinbuild/releases/Darwin9/), and [10.4](http://svn.macosforge.org/repository/darwinbuild/releases/Darwin8) is here

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd look at Selenium Grid. It should be possible to create a set of Selenium RC tests initially then use Grid to run the tests on your various platforms, including OS X as well as Windows and Linux. I haven't tried it with running tests in the cloud, but that might even be a possibility.